# Marchar check solo en una fila

Tags: datatables

Estoy usando datatables con la opción de checkbox, el problema es que necesito solo marchar un check,  si yo tengo una fila marchada con check y pulso en otro check de otra fila, el primero debe desactivarse y activarse el último.

Según datatables la instrucción sería esta:

```
select: {
        style: 'single'
    },
```

Las librerías que uso son:

```
<link type="text/css" href="//gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.11/css/dataTables.checkboxes.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <!-- CheckBox datatabla --->

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.11/js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js"></script>

 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

El código de la tabla sería este:

```
function fnTareas() {// Funcion que me pintara en la tabla las tareas del parte
    estadoChk=$('input:radio[name=estadoTarea]:checked').val(); //Tomo el valor del check


    parametros = {
        "estado": estado,
    };

    tblTareas = $('#tbl_Tareas').DataTable({
         dom:"iptlf",
            stateSave: true, //Guarda el estado de la tabla, orden, pagina etc
            "stateDuration": -1,
            "scrollY": '30vh',
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "scrollX": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
             "lengthChange": false,
            "bPaginate": false,
             "bInfo": false,
             "searching": true,
             "autoWidth":false,
            responsive: true,


            dom: "<'row'  <'col-sm-12 '<'#parte.titTablas'>f> <'col-6'>  >" +
           "<'row'   <'col-sm-12'tr> >" ,


            "language": {
                "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/Spanish.json",
            },

            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
                idTarea = sessionStorage.getItem('idTareaS');
                    if (aData["id"] == idTarea) {
                        $(nRow).addClass('selected');
                        fnTrabajadores(idTarea);
                    }
                },


            fnInitComplete: function(){
                $("#parte.titTablas").html('Tareas');
            },


            "destroy": "true",

            "ajax": {
                "beforeSend": function () {
                    $( "#cargando" ).show();
                },
                 "complete": function () {
                        $( "#cargando" ).hide();
               },
                "data": parametros,
                "url": "php/tareas_parte.php",
                "type": "POST",
                "dataSrc": "",

            },

            "order": [[2, 'desc']],
            'columnDefs': [

                { "width": "80%", "targets": 2 },
                {'targets': 1,'checkboxes': {'selectRow': true}},
                {"targets": 1,"orderable": false},
                { "responsivePriority": 1, "targets": 0 },
                { "responsivePriority": 2, "targets": 1 },
                { "responsivePriority": 3, "targets": 2 },
                { "responsivePriority": 100002, "targets": 3 },
                { "responsivePriority": 100003, "targets": 4 },
                { "responsivePriority": 100004, "targets": 5 },
                { "responsivePriority": 100005, "targets": 6 },
                { "responsivePriority": 100006, "targets": 7 },
            ],

            select: {
        style: 'single'
    },



            "columns": [
                {"className":'details-control', "orderable": false, "data": null,"defaultContent": '', "width": "5%"  },
                {"data": "id","width": "5%"},
                {"data": "name"}, 
                {"data": "hor_ini"}, 
                {"data": "hor_fin"}, 
                {"data": "fnc\\.name"}, 
                {"data": "nav\\.name"}, 
                {"data": "observa"}, 
            ],
        });
}
```

Comment: No conocía la herramienta, por curiosidad me puse a ver sus ejemplos y creo que choqué con lo que te interesa https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he solucionado de esta forma

```
 $('#tbl_Tareas tbody').off('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]');
 $('#tbl_Tareas tbody').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
        tblTareas.$("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);
         $(this).prop("checked", true);
});
```

El aporte que ha hecho el compañero Vladi es muy bueno, pero de esta forma me ahorro meter la CDN de select checkbox de datatables.